# Are the following definitions of a local property equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I have seen two different definitions of a local property of rings.

1. $P$ is a local property of rings if $P(A)$ is equivalent to $P(A_{\mathfrak p})$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak p$.
2. $P$ is a local property if $P(A)$ implies $P(A_f)$ for all $f\in A$, and $P(f_i)$ for $f_i$ such that $A=(f_1,f_2,...f_n)$ implies $P(A)$.

Here $P(A)$ denotes '$P$ holds for $A$'.
Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: I think the two definitions are only guaranteed to be equivalent when $A$ is noetherian. See [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44839/wikipedias-definition-of-locally-free-sheaf).